# SEVERE: Exception fetching webflow 2 key by introspection in Spring Security

Tags: spring-security

I am using Icefaces 3.3.0, Spring Security 3.0.5 with Hibernate 4.3.0 in my application. I am getting following exception every time the application is entering an XHTML page. Since I am using Icefaces, I don't have Spring MVC configurations in my Spring configuration file. I only try to use Spring Security for login page. The weird thing is, if my default login page is set to be a JSP page, the redirection to login page works fine. But if it's set to be an XHTML page, then the application throws following exception. The exception also happens when I try to  an XHTML page in another XHTML page.

**SEVERE: Exception fetching webflow 2 key by introspection: java.lang.NullPointerException**

This exception seems to be a Web flow 2.0 related one but I am not using it. Can somebody ever had this situation before and let me know how I should fix this exception?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, just for anybody who would encounter the same issue in the future, it was caused by ice:form tag. After I replaced it with h:form, the issue was gone.